# Using a ternary operator in a Objective-C format string

Tags: objective-c

I'm creating a formatted string in Objective-C. When one of the values is null or empty I'm wanting to use a "." instead. The string values are coming from a property on a singleton, I'm trying to use a ternary operator to do this but seem to failing since I'm trying to substring an empty string. Here is my code:

```
NSString *namelabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                      [[[User_Singleton sharedUser] valueForKey:@"LastName"] substringToIndex:1] ? : @"."];
```

Comment: What do you mean by failing? What is the value for the first name and last name that you are getting the wrong output for and what output are you expecting/getting?

Comment: If the value for the key "LastName" is null or empty I get an exception since I'm trying to substring it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty string will not get replaced in this way, because `@""` evaluates to `YES` in a ternary operator. To fix this, you could use the `length` property, which will be 0 for both `nil` and `@""`.

This would work:

```
NSString *namelabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
    [[User_Singleton sharedUser] valueForKey:@"FirstName"],
    [[[User_Singleton sharedUser] valueForKey:@"LastName"] length] ?
    [[[User_Singleton sharedUser] valueForKey:@"LastName"] substringToIndex:1] : @"."];
```

Comment: hmm when trying to get the length of "LastName" I'm getting an error of Property 'length' not found on object of type 'id'. Should it be '[[[User_Class sharedUser] valueForKey:@"LastName"] length]' instead?